# Передача данных из одного потока в другой на Андроиде

Tags: android, java, классы, многопоточность, строки

Предположим, у меня есть класс **Main** (Activity). Он отображает *main_layout.xml*. Еще у меня есть класс NotMain, в котором есть метод *stopWorking()*, который делает

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
            String output = "Test";
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

Из основного класса *Main* я вызываю этот метод, который после выполнения должен как-то отправить строку *output* обратно в основной поток, в *Main*, чтобы тот присвоил его *TextView* в *main_layout.xml*. Как можно это реализовать?

**Ps** Не могу привести полный код программы, он слишком запутан и велик для всеобщего обозрения, но я не могу разобраться именно с этой частью программы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если все-таки хотите использовать самописные потоки смотрите в сторону метода post у всех потомков View (в том числе TextView)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: А можно использовать уже готовые потоки? Просто у меня задача - получить код html-страницы в одном классе и передать его другому классу

Comment: Такие задачи можно решить с помощью AsyncTask, если я правильно понимаю о чем вы говорите. 

Вообще можете почитать тут [Processes and Threads][1]

 [1]:http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести пример использования или кусок кода? Просто я никак не могу найти моего случая (или похожего) в документации или в туториалах и плохо представляю себе, что и где писать

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask может этот пример подойдет

И что Вы подразумеваете под передачей от одного класса другому? Просто как параметр или что?

Comment: У меня есть 2 класса(файла). Из первого отправляется запрос на выполнение метода второго класса, который получает html-код страницы и отправляет его обратно в первый класс. Но получение html-страницы требует ее загрузку в новом потоке, но из нового потока нельзя (насколько я понял) передавать данные в старые потоки, только если с помощью Handler'ов вызывать другой метод класса. Но все равно непонятно, как передать то, что я получил в другом классе и в другом потоке первоначальному классу.

Comment: с потока в класс - asynctaks, с класса в класс - через сеттер или конструктор, или какойто метод, с активити в активити - интент

Comment: Ок, спасибо за советы, буду разбираться. Как я понял, легче будет перенести функцию в тот же класс, из которого я ее вызываю